# My followers won't stop attacking my horse!

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I use EFF and Convenient Horses, and lately I've been having this problem where my followers attack my supposedly friendly and essential horses and I can't get them to stop.

They stand there, slashing at the air, while the horse stands there doing nothing. I can't talk to them, and I don't think EFF has an option like AFT and Vilja do where you can command them not to attack whatever they're attacking.

[image]

Stopcombat, unfortunately, doesn't help. They immediately unsheathe their weapons and go back to attacking the horse.

Comment: Have you tried getting another horse?

Comment: @chillpill consider http://puush.me/ for your screenshot needs, the program is free and you'll have a non-ad saturated way of showing your screenshots to people.

Answer (score 5):

Try the [Followers Stop Fighting Each Other](http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/22030/?) mod.

It stop followers fighting each other, although it should work in your situation. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

If you're on PC, in command console try selecting the horse and using `kill`, then use `resurrect 1`.

Worked for me twice

Answer (score 0):

The followers are kinda bugged. To fix this, try one or more of the following below:

1. Download the mod [Followers Stop Fighting Each other](http://forums.nexusmods.com/index.php?/topic/752839-followers-stop-fighting-each-other/).
2. Cast a Calm spell on your followers, but only for a few seconds.
3. Use console commands. [Well, you said that you use stopcombat. They sheathed their swords, but then started attacking the horse/read 4].
4. Use cheats on the horse instead of the follower since the horse might be the enemy which is maybe why they are attacking the horse [Related to 3].

If neither of these work, then I don't know what else to do. you to spend the rest of the game with your hostile follower on your horse.